# Эффективность хранилища данных с точки зрения кэш-локальности

Tags: c++, c, malloc, виртуальная-память

Я хочу сделать хранилище данных, которое устроено приблизительно так:

1. Есть массив структур (умных указателей). Каждый такой указатель хранит смещение объекта в некотором стеке-массиве (где хранятся все объекты), размер объекта в байтах, и число владельцев объекта. Что-то типа:

```
struct ObjPtr {
    int disp;  // смещение объекта
    int size;  // размер объекта
    int count; // число владельцев
}

// где-то там в коде...
// Пусть в программе можно создать не более 1024 объектов. Это просто для примера.
ObjPtr* pointers = (ObjPtr*)calloc(1024, sizeof(ObjPtr));
```

2. Есть стек объектов:

```
char* obj_stack = (char*)calloc(64 * 1024 * 1024, sizeof(char)) // Допустим 64 МБ хватит
```

Этот стек представляет из себя просто обыкновенный массив байтов, с указателем на вершину стека. Объект добавляется в стек, на место куда указывает вершина, а затем вершина увеличивается на `sizeof(тип добавленного объекта)`. Когда объект нельзя добавить, но есть свободное место между между объектами, то весь этот массив компрессируется.

И вот везде в программе вместо указателей используются номера умных указателей, т.е.:

```
// Доступ к какому-либо объекту по указателю:
SomeObject* some_object = (SomeObject*)(obj_stack + pointers[objPointer].disp)
```

Сейчас отвлечемся от вопросов, как происходит компрессия, как хранить свободные указатели если объект освободился, выравнивания объектов, атомарности операций инкрементации/декрементации счетчика, удобно/неудобно и т.д.

**А вопрос вот в чем:**
Если я правильно понимаю работу виртуальной памяти, то процессор подгружает в кэш не несколько слов из памяти, а целую страницу размером 4Кб. В моем хранилище указатели расположены на одной странице виртуальной памяти, а объекты на других, т.е. **локальность** уже изначально нарушена. Я предполагаю, что стандартные аллокаторы каким-то магическим способом стараются соблюсти принцип локальности, чтобы процессор реже обращался напрямую к RAM, а почаще использовал кэш. Ну к примеру аллоцировать объект на той странице памяти где расположена структура (которая также динамически выделена), и принимающая указатель на этот вновь созданный объект. *(Хотя с другой стороны как функция аллокации может узнать где расположен адрес указателя который принимает адрес вновь выделенного блока, если ей передается только число объектов и их размер?..., стало быть аллокация происходит на рандомной странице?)*
Допустим моя программа долго работала, и так получилось, что связанные (по функциональности, бизнес логике) объекты разбросаны по всему стеку `obj_stack`. Как я уже сказал, процессор подгружает в кэш не несколько слов из памяти, а целую страницу. Тогда получается процессор будет скакать от страницы к странице. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в долговременной перспективе такое хранилище замедлит работу программы, по сравнению со стандартными аллокатором и стандартными алгоритмами сборки мусора? Если сборщик мусора какой-нибуть популярной системы типа Java/.NET, пройдется по куче, то скорее всего он будет стараться расположить соседние в графе объекты поближе.

И вообще должен ли я париться по поводу фрагментации на страницах виртуальной памяти и локальности объектов?

Comment: С пониманием работы виртуальной памяти у вас совсем плохо. Виртуальность памяти заключается в трансляции адресов из логических в физические при каждом обращении к памяти. Трансляция происходит на основе деления памяти на страницы. А кеш работает с кеш-линиями (обычно 64 байта). В некоторых задачах паренье по проводу фрагментации и локальности - основная работа.

Comment: "Я хочу сделать хранилище данных" не юзай calloc malloc и прочую нечисть для начала. "И вообще должен ли я париться по поводу фрагментации на страницах виртуальной памяти и локальности объектов?" после слов бизнЭс логика, можешь ниочём не парится вообще. Так как это обычно подразумевает, что можно и на С# и на PHP сделать и все будут довольны. А о кэше можно задуматься когда более 1'000'000 объектов в секунду надо обработать.